# Active Admin Rendering Action Leads to Route Error Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

This is my active admin model push_notification.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register PushNotification do
  actions :all, only: [:index]
  menu  priority: 12
  permit_params :name, :message, :enabled, :day_limit

  index do
    render partial: 'charts'
  end

end
```

and i have this in my app/views/admin/push_notification/_charts.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

But I cant reach here. Whenever i click push notification tab in my active admins page i get a route error..

```
No route matches [GET] "/admin/push_notification"
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined the route/resource in your routes.rb file?

Comment: yes...................

Comment: What do you get for `rake routes | grep push_notification`?

Comment: its something like this
admin_push_notification GET      /admin/push_notification(.:format)               admin/push_notification#index
                    send_notification GET      (/:locale)/send_notification(.:format)           push_notification#new {:locale=>/en|es/}